# How to change the value of the shape key in blender script?

Tags: blender, keyframe

I've defined a set of shape keys for a mesh. Is there a way to change the value (0..1) of a particular shape key and also insert a key frame for it through scripting?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i figured the code! :)

```
import bpy
ob=bpy.context.object
ob.data.shape_keys.key_blocks["eye"].keyframe_insert("value",frame=1)
for shape in ob.data.shape_keys.key_blocks:
    if (shape.name=='eye'):
    shape.value=1.0
    ob.data.shape_keys.key_blocks["eye"].keyframe_insert("value",frame=10)
```